# Passing parameters through events

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, parameter-passing, begininvoke

I have multiple classes in multiple projects, these classes have access to each other through a mediator class.

Whats happening at the moment is that Class A, fires and event, it is handled by a method in Class B (mediator), which fires an event that gets handled in Class C. This is the only way i can communicate fro A to C.

However within the method that is firing the event in Class A, i have an int variable that i would like to use in Class C.

Is there any ways of passing it though as an object, only in class C i can't access the information, i have even tried casting e to the class type. Maybe there is an easier way, i have tried just adding into the parameters and int param however i am using beginInvoke which won't accept that an i can't change this method as it it used elsewhere in the code.

```
    protected virtual void OnProcessing(EventHandler handler, EventArgs args, int p)
    {
        var temp = handler;
        if (temp != null)
        {
            var eventListeners = temp.GetInvocationList();
            foreach (EventHandler e in eventListeners)
            {
                e.BeginInvoke(this, args, EndAsyncImageAcquiredEvent, p);

            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new FatalException("No handler is attached to the camera's ImageAcquiredEvent");
        }
    }
```

this is the method in class A that fires the events

```
     progressPercentage = (int)Math.Round(sum, 0);

     OnProcessing(startProcess, null);
```

Onprocessing here is called from a method, i would like to pass into this method progressPercentage , but would like to know if there is a way of doing this by using the argument, or object and how would i retrieve it on the other side ie class c

**EDIT**

Sorry guys was kind of new to stackoverflow when i wrote this. What i was meaning to ask was if there was any way of passing through fields such as Title, ProgressPercentage, UserState, DisplayPercentage from class A to Class C. Class B was needed so that Class C and Class A had no relationship directly.

In the end up what i did was create a custom Event and a custom Event Args that contained all that fields i wanted to use.

```
public event ProgressHandler StartProgress;
```

ProgressHandler was my custom Event and was made up like so,

```
public delegate void ProgressHandler(object sender, ProgressEventArgs e);
```

And ProgressEventArgs was my customs argument, or the object that i was going to use to house my data

```
  public ProgressEventArgs(string title, int progressPercentage, bool displayPercentage, object userState) : base (progressPercentage, userState)
    {
        Title = title;
        ProgressPercentage = progressPercentage;
        UserState = userState;
        DisplayPercentage = displayPercentage;
    }
```

So the event got fired in Class A and handled in Class B. Class B then took this data and fired a new event, Class C then dealt with this.

```
Class A => Class B
Class B => Class C
```

So to add my fields into my custom object,

```
ProgressEventArgs e = new ProgressEventArgs("SomeName", 25, null, true);
```

Then to pass this data off i fired an event

```
StartProgress(null, e);
```

Comment: Adding your code and what you have tries till now can help

Comment: I assume that these events are custom events. So you can specify what you want to pass as argument(f.e. the `A` instance). Add a property in class `A` with this `int`, then pass `A` as sender to `B`, here you can pass it with this custom event to `C` or use a property in `B`.

Comment: It should be trivial to pass a parameter. Your question does not include enough code/details to understand the problem.

Comment: The code does not help very much. Please indicate A, B and C and what parts you can change.

Comment: Well, don't use EventArgs and don't use null.  Use, say, ProgressChangedEventArgs.  And do **not** use BeginInvoke(), whatever code subscribed the event isn't going to expect the event handler to run on an arbitrary threadpool thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot change the method then you have to pass the value by other means

1) Property can be an option for you, have a property in C and let it be assigned from B.

2) Write overload method that accepts one more parameter and that would do the job for you, this way you dont have to change existing method that is being called from multiple places.